# Why am I getting: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1) in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I'm doing an exercise to learn python and the question is simple, just to generate code that can print out if variable x is even or odd. I'm getting the correct output when I run the code, but I also receive the following error message:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Here's my chunk:

```
x = 1
if (x % 2) == 0:
  print("EVEN")

else:
  if(x % 2) != 0:
    print("ODD")
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the error message along with the correct output?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me. I suspect you have a non-printing character in your script. Maybe a BOM character. Check the file with a hex editor.

Comment: Is this in a file, or are you typing it to the terminal?  Terminal input doesn't like blank lines.

Comment: @FrankYellin it's in terminal. I'll give it a try with no blank lines, thanks!

Comment: fyi you dont need the second if statement (within the else statement)

Answer (score 2):

More precise followup to my previous comment.

To the terminal, a blank line is interpreted as "the input is finished; go ahead an evaluate it".

When the evaluator saw the blank line, it assumed that your `if` statement was finished.  It saw that your condition was `False` and did nothing.

Then it saw a raw `else:`.  Whoa.  That's a syntax error.

Then it saw the second `if` statement, and happily evaluated it and printed `ODD`'.